# How do I access the mini fort in Borderlands 2 Southern Shelf?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the Southern Shelf area there is a mini "fort" for lack of a better term next to the small bandit town (near the first Handsome Jack audio recording).  Inside the bandit town there is a drawbridge that is up and a sign that says "scram".  Drum music can be heard around this area.  It appears to be the only way to access the adjacent "fort", but I can't figure out how to make the bridge drop so I can cross.  I also can't find any reference to this area anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Access to this fort will open automatically as you progress through the main quest. Claptrap will lower the drawbridge eventually :)